# Contained in NP and Turing-reduction from an NP-complete problem $\Rightarrow$ NP-complete under Karp reductions?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, open-problem, reductions

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Do many-one reductions and Turing reductions define the same class NPC](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/686/do-many-one-reductions-and-turing-reductions-define-the-same-class-npc)
>   [Many-one reductions vs. Turing reductions to define NPC](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/138/many-one-reductions-vs-turing-reductions-to-define-npc)

Let $P,Q \subseteq \Sigma^*$ be languages such that $P$ and $Q$ are both in NP. Assume that $P$ is NP-complete under Karp reductions (there is a polynomial time many-one reduction from 3-SAT to $P$) and there is a Turing-reduction from $P$ to $Q$, i.e. there is a polynomial-time algorithm which decides $P$ when given oracle-access to $Q$. Intuitively this means that deciding $Q$ is as hard as deciding any problem in NP, while at the same time $Q$ is in NP, so Q cannot be ``harder'' than NP. Does this imply that $Q$ is NP-complete under Karp reductions, i.e. does this imply the existence of a polynomial-time many-one reduction from 3-SAT to Q? Any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: In summary: $\mathbf{3SAT} \ \le_m^\rm{P} \ \mathbf{P} \ \le_T^\rm{P} \ \mathbf{Q}$, where $\le_m^\rm{P}$ denotes polynomial-time many-one (Karp) reduction, and $\le_T^\rm{P}$ denotes polynomial-time Turing reduction.

Comment: Note that problem $P$ plays no real part in your question, you may as well replace it by SAT.

Comment: @András: Why is UNSAT NP-complete under Cook reducibility?  If I am not mistaken, it implies that UNSAT∈NP (by definition of NP-completeness) and therefore it cannot happen unless NP=coNP.

Comment: Don't close this question. It's a real question. I don't know the answer, and I don't believe anybody else has given the answer, either.

Comment: I agree with Peter, this is interesting question.

Comment: @Peter: No one has argued that this is not a real question.  This question should be closed because it is an exact duplicate of the [existing question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/686/do-many-one-reductions-and-turing-reductions-define-the-same-class-npc).  Answers should be posted on the other page, not here.

Comment: @Peter: I know the definition of Turing reductions, but you have not explained why UNSAT is _NP-complete_ under Turing reducibility.  NP-completeness means that it belongs to NP and it is NP-hard.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: O.K. I agree with you now. I somehow was thinking András had said "hard" and not "complete".

Comment: Have removed my incorrect comment above: as Peter points out, UNSAT is not in NP.

Comment: Related: [many-one reductions vs Turing-reductions to define NPC](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/138/many-one-reductions-vs-turing-reductions-to-define-npc)

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: The "duplicate" question is actually two *different* questions which the OP seems to think are the same. While the answers to that question are fairly reasonable, is it a good idea to leave that as the question of record on this topic?

Comment: I fixed the duplicate question http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/686/do-many-one-reductions-and-turing-reductions-define-the-same-class-npc by changing it's wording, and now I feel O.K. about closing this one.