# Oracle complexity classes and hardness under different notions of reduction

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reductions, oracles

Let **C** be a complexity class, and let *L* be a language such that **P**<sup>**C**</sup> ⊆ **P**<sup>*L*</sup>. Then it’s natural (and easy to prove) that *L* is **C**-hard with respect to Cook reductions (polytime Turing reductions).

This fact is not (known to be) true for *Karp* (polytime many-one) reductions: for instance, we have **P**<sup>**NP**</sup> ⊆ **P**<sup>UNSAT</sup>, but UNSAT is not **NP**-hard under Karp reductions (unless **NP** = **coNP**). On the other hand, most of the times we use Karp reductions to order problems by hardness, since they seem to provide a finer structure.

> Are there some “natural” or “interesting” sufficient conditions for **P**<sup>**C**</sup> ⊆ **P**<sup>*L*</sup> to imply that *L* is **C**-hard under Karp reductions?

If that implication held for all **C** and *L*, then the two notions of reducibility would coincide (see Tsuyoshi Ito’s comment below); I would be interested in knowing about any interesting class of problems where this happens, if any is known.

Comment: related: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/686/do-many-one-reductions-and-turing-reductions-define-the-same-class-npc and http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/138/many-one-reductions-vs-turing-reductions-to-define-npc

Comment: If C is a class of decision problems and L is a decision problem, P^C⊆P^L is equivalent to C⊆P^L (one direction of the implications follows from C⊆P^C, the other from P^{P^L}=P^L), that is, L being C-complete under polynomial-time Turing reducibility.  Therefore, your question is indeed the same as asking for the condition for the completeness under poly-time Turing reducibility and the completeness under poly-time many-one reducibility to coincide.

Comment: What you write is certainly true; however, I wasn’t asking for result holding for all **C** and *L*; instead, I was wondering about *some* conditions on **C** and *L* implying that *L* is **C** hard wrt Karp reductions. According to your observation, I guess my question could be rephrased as “Do Karp and Cook reducibility coincide for some class of languages?”.

Comment: What I meant is that you were asking for a condition on C and L such that L being C-complete under poly-time Turing reducibility and L being C-complete under poly-time many-one reducibility are equivalent.  And I should have written “hard” instead of “complete”.  So we do not have any disagreement on this.

Comment: Sorry, apparently I misinterpreted the purpose of your remark.